# Explorer constantly hanging

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

So I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate (x64) an AMD 8150 on an Asus Crosshair V motherboard with all the latest and greatest patches, and I am experiencing frequent Explorer freezes.

I've included the information I've grepped from the Event Viewer below:

```
The program Explorer.EXE version 6.1.7601.17567 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel.
 Process ID: 13a4
 Start Time: 01cdb2968999c6fd
 Termination Time: 0
 Application Path: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
 Report Id: c000ba44-1e8b-11e2-9ae7-000272ddf2b0



- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Application Hang 

  - EventID 1002 

   [ Qualifiers]  0 

   Level 2 

   Task 101 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2012-10-25T10:08:44.000000000Z 

   EventRecordID 14626 

   Channel Application 

   Computer RyanMain-PC 

   Security 


- EventData 

   Explorer.EXE 
   6.1.7601.17567 
   13a4 
   01cdb2968999c6fd 
   0 
   C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE 
   c000ba44-1e8b-11e2-9ae7-000272ddf2b0 
   430072006F00730073002D0074006800720065006100640000000000 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Binary data:


In Words

0000: 00720043 0073006F 002D0073 00680074 
0008: 00650072 00640061 00000000  


In Bytes

0000: 43 00 72 00 6F 00 73 00   C.r.o.s.
0008: 73 00 2D 00 74 00 68 00   s.-.t.h.
0010: 72 00 65 00 61 00 64 00   r.e.a.d.
0018: 00 00 00 00               ....
```

Any idea what "Cross-thread" here means?

Comment: Have you checked the Action Centre (in the Control Panel) in case there is a known issue? Do you have any unusual programs or add-ons running that would affect Explorer? Try http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be many programs hooked into explorer.exe from various places to handle different file types and to provide information.  I had a similar problem and would suggest getting an idea of all that is hooked into your explorer.exe and possibly disabling everything and then adding them back 1 at a time until you run across the problem.

One of the tools I used was Sysinternals - Autoruns for Windows.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902

Or you can use "ShellExView" from http://www.nirsoft.net ... does not require install.

Best of luck,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of icons in your desktop (200+), even if you have them hidden, Explorer may crash after a resolution change. You can create a folder in your desktop, move everything in there, and try again to see if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here can be many ways.
1. Replace your Explorer.exe with another (of the same version)
2. Your PC is slow (which is least possible)
3. It's a virus, which tries to get into Explorer.exe. Then I recommend you Kaspersky Internet Security
4. Try to remember what you have done before it, and restore your system to previous state.
5. Restore your system from backups.
6. It can come from patches/updates. Sometimes updates can crash some system files.
   Delete last updates latest updates (this is the most possible for your case).

Answer (score -1):

Well, the problem is that what error messages say is decided by the developers of the application. The other problem is that that may not actually be an error message.

It gets displayed as a string, and it is a message meant to be human-readable as a string, but the event logger gives the hex values for the entire string, including the NULL terminating character. It may simply be the last thing reported to the operating system before IE stopped responding to input.

The problem with 'cross thread' is that IE is an extremely multi-threaded process. There are threads controlling the display, threads for each window, threads for each tab... What the developer might actually have meant when they typed "Cross thread" into a printf statement is anyone's guess.

For a number of reasons, I advise you to solve the problem by switching browsers. For one thing, web developers hate having to change their programs to be compatible with IE, and as a result many simply don't. So, by switching, you'd find out how much nicer the internet can look. Additionally, IE has a (recent) history of egregious security flaws. If the hanging doesn't happen with other programs, it may well simply be an abstruse and frustrating problem with IE. And since problems go with IE like syrup goes with waffles, my informed recommendation is switch browsers. Try chrome, firefox, or opera.

Although this answer may not be as viscerally satisfying as knowing precisely why Microsoft has failed you, it certainly will solve your problem.

Disclaimer: In the event that Microsoft ever wants to hire me, the opinions expressed above regarding Microsoft should be viewed only as the misguided opinions of rebellious youth. However, should that event not come to pass, I will continue to side with everyone else who has seen Windows 8, and say that it is an unfortunately comprehensive myriad of all the worst imaginable approaches to UI design in one disgusting melange.

Comment: Hey, stop writing a lecture !) 
He talks about **Windows Explorer** not **Internet Explorer**

Comment: SEARAS is correct, I am talking about Windows / File Explorer, not Internet Explorer. I run Waterfox as my browser of choice.

Comment: A) Good man. And B) I'll admit I'm mainly a *nix guy. Sometimes I forget about the variety of explorer.exe you mean. Sorry! Ignore my thing.

Comment: Also, since SEARAS mentioned AV software might be a good idea, and a large part of my job was looking into AV software... 'Avast' is generally well-received on Windows. Avoid McAfee and Norton like the plague.